# Z-index doesn't work with dropotron-meu and bx-slider

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I'm using two jquery plugins: dropotron-menu and bx-slider. But the menu does not overlap the image of bxslider. Could you help me? Have changed the positions and z-index, but nothing happened ...

my site is: http://www.amexassessoria.com/site-teste/#

Comment: Can you give some more information? A http://jsfiddle.net/ link perhaps?

Comment: http://www.amexassessoria.com/site-teste/#

Comment: I found a very interesting article on `z-index` hope it helps http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Comment: You have an error in your code, `style.css 404 (Not Found)` you are trying to link to `style.css` which doesn't exist on the server... You might also want to consider loading times for large images, specifically your image `obras.JPG` which is `6.3MB`!! reduce this to speed up loading times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#header {
    border-top: 3px solid #3c9cd9;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.84;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #3489bf;
    margin-bottom: 0;

    /*Newly add these two css styles*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Will resolve your probelm

Comment: Thank you. Not thought about changing the header, thought the problem was on the image of bxslider

Comment: @user3507035 Yes here we are updating z-index on header we are giving higher priority in z-index stacking order hence its children menu will appear over slider Good Luck!